# returning array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a structure interval and `*re[]` as array of pointers to structure. In function `insert()`, I am able to store the required data in an array of pointers but when I return the array of pointers as `return re`, a warning is shown "*return from incompatible type*".

```
typedef struct interval
{
int start;
int end;
}interval;


interval *re[100000];

interval * insert(interval *intervals,interval newInterval,int sz, int *len)
{
    int size_i=0;
    for(size_i=0;size_i<=sz+1;size_i++)
    {
        re[size_i]=(interval *)malloc(sizeof(intervals[0]));
    }

    re[0]->start=intervals[0].start;
    re[0]->end=intervals[0].end;
    re[1]->start=intervals[1].start;
    re[1]->end=intervals[1].end;

    printf("%d,%d",re[0]->start,re[0]->end);
    printf("\t%d,%d",re[1]->start,re[1]->end);
    return re; //Statement where i am getting warning
}


int main(void)
{

interval intervals[100]={{5,6},{8,10},{11,16},{20,24}};
interval newInterval={};
interval * ret;
int sz=4,i;
int *len;
ret=insert(intervals,newInterval,sz,len);

printf("\n%d,%d",ret[0].start,ret[0].end);
printf("\n%d,%d",ret[1].start,ret[1].end);
}
```

In `main()` I want to receive the array of pointers in another pointer so that I can iterate over the returned array of pointers to structure.
But here I am getting some addresses.

Comment: Please, when reporting some error/warning output from the compiler, make the effort of putting it exactly as it appears on your screen.  Your interpretation of the message can be wrong and so, you can be changing the complete error message meaning from the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

`re` is of type `interval **` and so the return type of your function should be `interval **`. Corresponding changes should be made.

Or,

`re` is already declared global, so it is not needed to be returned from the function.

There are several other areas in your code which may give a compiler warning.

- `interval newInterval={};` should be replaced by `interval newInterval;` as the standard forbids the use of empty initializer braces
- `len` is used uninitialized in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `insert()` function should return `interval**` because your `re` is an array of pointers. Now your code is:

```
interval** insert(interval *intervals,interval newInterval,int sz, int *len)
...
interval** ret;
...
printf("\n%d,%d",ret[0]->start,ret[0]->end);
printf("\n%d,%d",ret[1]->start,ret[1]->end);
```